# Representing Work Hours/Schedule in Relational Database

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, schedule

I'm developing a searchable database for temps/part-timers, and I have no experience implementing their work hours availability. I have already developed the schema for the employee, skills, agent and customer. Now I need to capture the hourly availability of the employee.

The system should be able to represent any combination of 24/7 hourly schedules, i.e.:

- Mon 8-9am, Tue 1-5am, Wed 3-10pm;
- Mon-Fri 1-4pm;
- Sat-Sun 8am-6pm;

and of course there will be the occasional outlier who will be available full-time, although I'm thinking in the employee table there will be a boolean field for full-time, and this schedule table/system will only be consulted if the employee is part-time.

Any experience/guidance/direction for this would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would model it by focusing on the availability for each day for each user with the following columns:

a) Day (1-7) where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday following the MySQL conventions

b) Start time - starting time can be null if not available

c) End Time - end time can be null if not available

d) Notes - any notes on that day's availability

e) userid (the id of the user whose schedule is being shown)

f) Not Available - Yes/No

This means that each user will have 7 availability records. However on the user face you can carry out tweaks to have data copies from on day to another

Comment: thanks, @ssmusoke , working on this. will `Day` be an `INT` type? what exactly do you mean "MySQL conventions"? :D

Comment: There are different conventions for day of week, but MySQL uses 1 as Sunday and 7 for Saturday, yet some languages use 0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday. I recommend that you use tinyint unsigned (meaning it can only be +ve), which goes from 1 - 128, as that will be sufficient for your needs. Int goes up to 2billion so you do not need all that.

Comment: aaiyt, what i finally did was to add an extra table `Empl_Schedule` having only the fields `Empl_ID`, `Empl_Day` and `Empl_Time` - all tinyint unsigned, all as composite primary key. `Empl_Day` will have values `1,2..7` and `Empl_Time` `0,1..23`. one row entry will be made for each hour of any day that the employee's available. finally on the `Employee` table there's a boolean field `FullTime`. thanks, @ssmusoke

Comment: A single column for time does not take into account, 8-9am, 3-10pm etc, that is why you need a start and end time columns

Comment: it's actually possible: assuming Empl_ID is `12`, Mon 8-9am, 3-10pm will be `(12, 2, 8), (12, 2, 15), (12, 2, 16), (12, 2, 17), (12, 2, 18), (12, 2, 19), (12, 2, 20), (12, 2, 21)` :)

Comment: That will be difficult for you to query later as you need to rollup the data, better is Monday 8 - 9, (12, 2, 8, 9), Monday 3-10pm, (12, 2, 15, 22) where each period is self contained and you can display it on a calendar. In your case you may have 7 x 24 records for each employee, what happens when you have 1000 employees?

Comment: yeap... it's the scaling that bothers me. will definitely work this one out again, thanks @ssmusoke

Answer (score -1):

Why not just creating an association betwen intervals and users on a time period ?
If you know, it'a 1 week recurrent, you choose any given week.
If you know, it's 1 month recurrent, you choose any given month etc...

StartAvailableDateTime1 DATETIME, 
AvailableDateTime2 DATETIME, 
UserID INT